# Validação de TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código que limita um `TextBox` a receber apenas números e virgula:

```
private void txtTempoAcel1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != (char)8 && e.KeyChar == 48)
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

Porém tenho vários `TextBox` e gostaria de replicar esse código para todos. Tem alguma forma de eu replicar essa validação para todos os `TextBox` sem que eu coloque esse código no evento `KeyPress` de cada um deles ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Registe esse método como *handler* do evento KeyPress para todos os TextBox:

```
textBox1.KeyPress += txtTempoAcel1_KeyPress;
textBox2.KeyPress += txtTempoAcel1_KeyPress;
textBox3.KeyPress += txtTempoAcel1_KeyPress;
textBox4.KeyPress += txtTempoAcel1_KeyPress;
...
...
```

Talvez seja conveniente dar outro nome ao método.

Answer (score 4):

Uma outra forma de resolver é criando uma herança de `TextBox`

```
public class MeuTextBox : TextBox
{
    private bool _validaDigito;

    public MeuTextBox()
    {
        ValidaDigito = true;
    }

    public bool ValidaDigito
    {
        get { return _validaDigito; }
        set
        {
            _validaDigito = value;

            if (value)
                KeyPress += Text_KeyPress;
            else
                KeyPress -= Text_KeyPress;
        }
    }

    private void Text_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != (char)8 && e.KeyChar == 48)
            e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Ao dar build, seu `MeuTextBox` estará disponível na ToolBox para ser usado.

[image: textbox personalizado]